# Managing authentication across micro-services

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, jwt, microservices

We currently have a semi-microservice architecture:

- API (PHP)
- Frontend website (React / Node)
- Backend management website (React / Node)
- Backend organisation website (React / Node)

We would like to start writing some other backend services in Node that add new endpoint to our existing API. Our existing API manages users and authentication through JWTs.

***Whats the best approach to manage user authentication across services?***

***Should we split out our auth and create an API gateway?***

Comment: 2 approaches, centralized authentication or firewall authentication

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microservice Authentication strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644916/microservice-authentication-strategy)